# react native how to disable android dev mode

Tags: android, react-native

I've read that disabling the dev mode in Android can help speed up some of the issues with the Android emulator as it keeps not responding at the moment. How do I disable dev mode? I can't find any bool value or anything anywhere in the react native files.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you open the menu in react-native apps (F2 or rage shake) and choose dev options, there is option to switch off dev mode along with other options like live reload

Comment: When I press F2 and then click through to dev settings, I only get the following options: FPS debugging, Animations FPS summaries, auto reload on JS change and debug server host for device. None of these seem to be related to dev mode.

Comment: May I ask which version of react-native and android you are using? I am using 0.14.2 and 5.0.1 respetively

Comment: I appears as though I'm using version 0.12.0 of react-native from my package.son file, I did think I was on 0.14. I can't see where the version for my Android is mentioned. Do you know of the best way to upgrade my version of react-native?

Comment: I've upgraded my version of react native to 0.14.2 and now have that option. However it's still running slowly, possibly a slight improvement.

Comment: The boost depends on the operations you were using. Not all operations are faster in dev mode. It would be great if you could accept the answer

Comment: You can also open the menu with the ads command: ./adb shell input keyevent 82

Answer (score 7):

I preferred the way to build apk with a simple gradle command line.
I need to build a app-preprod.apk with bundle react native JS and turn off its dev mode to set some different api hostname settings from release build.

After looks over google and stackoverflow, I ended up to find `PROJECT_PATH/android/app/react.gradle`, and it turns out react will only turn off the dev mode when android build variants name contains "release".

```
// Set up dev mode
def devEnabled = !targetName.toLowerCase().contains("release")
if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
    commandLine "cmd", "/c", "react-native", "bundle", "--platform", "android", "--dev", "${devEnabled}",
            "--entry-file", entryFile, "--bundle-output", jsBundleFile, "--assets-dest", resourcesDir
} else {
    commandLine "react-native", "bundle", "--platform", "android", "--dev", "${devEnabled}",
            "--entry-file", entryFile, "--bundle-output", jsBundleFile, "--assets-dest", resourcesDir
}
```

So I just refactor the devEnabled follow my custom setting devInXxx

```
def devEnabled = config."devIn${targetName}" == false ? false : !targetName.toLowerCase().contains("release")
```

And set build type variants dev mode to false in `PROJECT_PATH/android/build.gradle`

```
project.ext.react = [
bundleInPreprod: true,
devInPreprod: false]
```

To clean the build, remove all files under "PROJECT_PATH/android/app/build"
and run gradle assemble the build variant only by

```
PROJECT_PATH/android$ ./gradlew assemblePreprod
```

which will build the app-preprod.apk, which bundled js and turn dev mode off. Normally under the folder `PROJECT_PATH/android/app/build/output/apk/`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try running `npm start`, then press  `d` to switch the current mode, then stop npm by `ctr+c` and then run again `exp start` you will find the enhancement feature became On and the mode became production.